# Does Apple provide a web site with content of `man` pages for the command-line commands bundled with Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, search, websites, documentation

I want to provide URL links to [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) content at apple.com as an authoritative source of information. Describing and quoting the local man page is awkward.

Does Apple provide man pages on the web?

Answer (score 22):

Hello from the future world of 2022!

As [benwiggy mentioned below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374726/324784), the short answer is https://ss64.com/osx. It's the only reasonably up-to-date, online-viewable, searchable, and cross-referenced repository of macOS man pages that I'm personally aware of right now.

*That site's a fantastic resource for Windows scripting languages, too, if you are of that persuasion. If it has helped you, and you're feeling magnanimous, maybe [buy the site's maintainer, Simon, a beer](https://ss64.com/docs/), because he's been hosting that site and answering posts in the forums for [decades](https://sitereport.netcraft.com/?url=ss64.com).*

Here are some other options, though:

- you can find the raw [roff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roff_(software)) source for some commands at https://opensource.apple.com/source, or with a web search, *e.g.* `site:opensource.apple.com/source stat.1`

  - see below for how to format that for on-screen reading or as PostScript
- if the man page you're looking for is in section [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/intro.2.html), [3](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/intro.3.html), or 3x of the manual, you can link to the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/)

  - if you need a man page for one of the other sections, you could link to an [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org) or FreeBSD version of the man page instead; most of the "user commands" (section 1) in macOS came from BSD anyway
- [Mojave (10.14) man pages](https://www.unix.com/man-page-mojave-repository.php) on unix.com

  - poor site design, not effectively searchable, and not cross-referenced
- https://github.com/keith/xcode-man-pages, viewable online [here](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/); thanks to cachius for the tip

  - an HTML export of Xcode's man pages, with section anchors, but not cross-referenced to other man pages
  - either clone the repo or use the included script to generate on your own system
- [Darwin man pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20170719143432/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/indexguts.html) on the Wayback Machine

  - this is a July 2017 capture, for OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), and there are still some holes, so you may need to go back farther in time with the Wayback Machine to get certain pages

#### I have a Mac, why wouldn't I just use `man` in the terminal?

It's when you *don't* have a Mac that these resources are useful, for example, when writing shell scripts which need to work on Linux *and* macOS/BSD.

In that regard, the [Heirloom Project](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/)'s man pages can also be helpful for ascertaining what is the lowest common denominator behavior (*e.g.*, which options are *definitely* supported) for many "Unix toolbox" commands.

#### Formatting roff source mini how-to

You can format the raw [roff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roff_(computer_program)) source of the man pages on opensource.apple.com into something human readable like this:

1. copy the "plain text" URL:

   [image]
2. fetch that URL with `curl` and format it for viewing on-screen with `groff`:

   ```bash
   # use 'wget -qO -' if you don't have 'curl'
   curl -s https://opensource.apple.com/source/grep/grep-28/grep/doc/grep.1 \
     | groff -man -T utf8 \
     | less
   ```

Some side notes about that `groff` command:

- add `-rLL=${COLUMNS}n` to use the full width of your terminal, if 80 columns doesn't do it for you; *the `man` command usually does some magic to autodetect this from your terminal size* ([reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18491/278323))
- you can substitute `groff -man -T ps > ~/Desktop/grep.1.ps` for that last part to get a beautiful PostScript manual page that you can open and print with Preview.app, if that's your thing

Comment: basically "Hello from the future world" is correct for every given answer there is.

Comment: _If_ the future world actually fixed your problem, _and_ bothered to report back. But sometimes the future world just locks your thread instead, with [no resolution for anybody](https://xkcd.com/979/). `:/`

Comment: A very extensive resource is https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/  - _A HTML export of Xcode's man pages._ See the [repo](https://github.com/keith/xcode-man-pages) for the generating script. Try this one if the other resources don't list your manpage. @TheDudeAbides Maybe you can add it to the list?

Comment: @cachius You can add it to the answer yourself - your edit will be placed in a queue for higher reputation users to approve

Answer (score 12):

The old online index seems have to vanished. You can however find the source code of manual pages on https://opensource.apple.com/. This site hosts historical versions as well.

For example:

- fputs(3) - https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.200.26/stdio/FreeBSD/fputs.3.auto.html
- ls(1) - https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272.220.1/ls/ls.1.auto.html
- grep(1) - https://opensource.apple.com/source/grep/grep-28/grep/doc/grep.1.auto.html

Unfortunately there is no overview of all manual pages, so you have to manually check directory indexes or use something like `site:opensource.apple.com/source "ls.1"` in DuckDuckGo or Google.

Comment: The `site:opensource.apple.com/source` trick is brilliant. For a browseable list of _all_ manual pages from _all_ sections of the manual (albeit dating back to the OS X 10.9 days) see [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374715/324784) below.

Answer (score 5):

In the past, Apple provided these pages online, for example:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html for the **ls** command.

Source: [Dr Drang](http://leancrew.com/all-this/2016/05/man-alive-again/)

Now you would need to find them mirrored elsewhere or use https://archive.org

Answer (score 4):

There are some MacOS man pages [here](https://ss64.com/osx/), though I don't know how complete the list is.

I used to use this utility, [Bwana](https://www.bruji.com/bwana/), which converts man pages to HTML in Safari on-the-fly. It hasn't been updated for some time, though the source code is available.

Comment: SS64 is a _really_ good resource for anyone who works in a command-line environment, on _any_ OS. It's well-structured, comprehensive, _and_ uncluttered. If only Microsoft's (or Apple's) official documentation were up to [this standard](https://ss64.com/docs/site.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [tldr++](https://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/a-better-tldr)

A quick an easy way to see a couple of examples of the use of a command.

**Update to answer comment**

Here are two examples, so one knows what it looks like.

[image: tldr 1]

[image: tldr 2]

So I'd say that it's a possible addition to the man-pages.

Comment: What does it do? are they web pages of macOS commands or of Linux commands? An answer should work without a link - the link is there for citation or further information

Comment: @mmmmmm - I've added some examples.

Comment: If it is text please paste as text - I can't read the writing

Comment: WHere does the information come from? Is it actual;ly Apple or is it Linux stuff which is often wrong

Comment: TLDR shows not man pages but curated usage examples. This didn't answer how to get specifically OSX results.  I suppose it defaults to current OS, but the question is most useful when _not_ running on OSX, otherwise one would just use `man`.  The interactive tldr++ apparently takes an env var e.g. `env TLDR_OS=osx tldr cal` (untested).  https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr-python-client takes a flag e.g. `tldr --platform=linux cal` vs. `tldr --platform=osx cal` show different flags ✔.  Both take data from https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/ repo (e.g. `pages.es/osx` dir has Spanish OSX)