# How to delete files under /Library/StagedExtensions?

Tags: monterey, kernel-extensions, apple-silicon

I try to remove **macFUSE** from my system, and I deleted the followings already:

- `/Library/Filesystems/macfuse.fs`
- `/Library/Frameworks/macFUSE.framework`

Then I found a directory as `/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Filesystems/macfuse.fs`. Naturally I tried to run `sudo rm -rf /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Filesystems/macfuse.fs` but I got `Operation not permitted`.

How do I delete them?

I'm using Monterey (12.4) on Apple M1 Pro.

Comment: Did you use the "Remove FUSE" button on the macFUSE preference pane?  If not, reinstall and then uninstall using that button.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer on StackOverflow when faced with the same problem.

This should help to clear the folder:

```
sudo kextcache --clear-staging
```

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions)

Comment: It would be good to have an answer for individual extensions.

Comment: @benwiggy, I think this clears them all. The `-prune-staging` option from [the man page](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/kextcache.8.html) sounded less scary, and that's the one _I_ used, but unless you've got an actual "staged" driver waiting for your confirmation in System Preferences, the end result is probably the same.

Comment: `kextcache` _does_ seem to accept `--clear-staging` (two dashes), but all options are documented in [the man page](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/kextcache.8.html) ([ref](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374715/324784)) with a single dash. It might be worth an edit to make the answer match.